# Google Maps losses mousemove Event Listener after simultaneous dragstart and dragend events

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I am working over a Google Map API application, but I got into a bug where mousemove event listener is lost after a mousedown event. It restores activity if the map is dragged or zoomed. Please check this simple example here, where the problem can be replicated after you click on the map for a while:

https://jsfiddle.net/dninov81/95ybk1wt/31/

```
let map;
let marker;
const textField = document.getElementById('text')

function initialize() {
  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), {
    center: {
      lat: 52.50871874907,
      lng: 6.2503252411254
    },
     mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
     zoom: 15,
  })
    map.addListener( 'mousemove', onDrawMove);
  map.addListener( 'mousedown', onDrawDown);
}

initialize();
function onDrawMove(e) {
    textField.innerHTML = e.latLng
}
function onDrawDown(e) {
        textField.innerHTML = e.latLng
    if(marker) {
        marker.setMap(null)
    }
    marker = new google.maps.Marker({
      position: e.latLng,
      map: map
    });

    marker.setMap(map);
    
}
```

Here is a record of the problem, where when mouseover listener is active we can see the coordinates are correctly displayed in the text field and once it stops, only the mousedown event is registered. After a zoom change the mouseover event resumes.
https://youtu.be/gb3A83g4Qt0

If anyone experience similar behavior I would like to know why is this?

UPDATE:
We managed to isolate the problem and it accurses when dragstart and dragend events are fired simultaneously due to fast clicking sometimes. Still the problem persist it also occurs in google official event handling tool here:
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/events

Answer (score 1):

It turns out it is a known bug and here is the solution from the issue tracker:

```
var dragStartCenter = null;
google.maps.event.addListener(map, "dragstart", function() {
  dragStartCenter = map.getCenter();
});

google.maps.event.addListener(map, "dragend", function() {
  if (dragStartCenter && dragStartCenter.equals(map.getCenter())) {
// execute panBy() if the map has not been moved during dragging.
    map.panBy(0, 0);
  }
});
```

Comment: This actually seems to work...